# How can I use a recent version of GCC in GitHub CI?

Tags: github, gcc, cmake, continuous-integration, github-ci

I have a C++ project on GitHub with which I use GitHub CI. My workflow is configured to run on Linux and Windows through the `strategy` property:

```
runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
strategy:
  matrix:
    os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest]
```

This has worked well for me so far, with Cmake identifying the compiler as `GNU 9.3.0`. However, I would now like to use an experimental feature added in GCC 10 in my project, and so my build fails due to the old compiler version.

How can I use a more recent version of GCC from my GitHub CI workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the linux build you can use the following build step to switch the default gcc to gcc-10.

```yaml
- name: switch to gcc-10 on linux
  if: matrix.configurations.os == "ubuntu-latest"
  run: |
    sudo apt install gcc-10 g++-10
    sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-10 100 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-10 --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-10
    sudo update-alternatives --set gcc /usr/bin/gcc-10
```

The first 2 lines in the script should be optional, as gcc-10 is already installed in ubuntu-latest. But it doesn't hurt much to have them there and it might help to make clear what is happening and how to reproduce the build locally.
You can check the [manpage for update-alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/update-alternatives.1.html) if you are interested how this works.

windows-latest uses visual-studio as it's default compiler, but since you only asked about gcc I suppose that it already supports the c++ features you are using?

Comment: I see, thank you. This answer works and addresses the question well, so I'll accept it. I ended up going in a slightly different direction, because it turns out gcc-10 and gcc-11 had bugs in the feature I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

@wirew0rm posted an excellent answer, which works very well generically. It's useful to note that one is allowed to use `sudo` on the GitHub CI runners, and so one simply needs to install the desired packages:

```
sudo apt install gcc-10 g++-10

# or
sudo apt install gcc-11 g++-11

# or, for very recent Clang:
wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
chmod +x llvm.sh
sudo ./llvm.sh 12
sudo apt-get install libc++-12-dev libc++abi-12-dev
```

Then, because I was using CMake, I could set the `CXX` environment variable instead of using `sudo update-alternatives`:

```
echo "CXX=g++-10" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

The subsequent CMake configure step would then select g++-10 as the C++ compiler.